# Extra newline character needed

Tags: c++, error-handling

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a;
    do
    {
        /* First reset the flag and then clean the buffer*/
        cin.ignore();
        cin.clear();
        /* Input the number from the user*/
        cout << "Enter number\n";
        cin >> a;
        /*Diplay appropiate error if the input was wrong*/
        if(cin.fail())
        {
            cout << "invalid input \n";
        }
        /*Display the number if the input was valid*/
        else
        {
            cout << "number entered is : " << a << endl;
        }
    }
    while(cin.fail());  //repeat until the input is correct
    return 0;
}
```

Every time I execute this program I have to enter a new line first and then the `cout<<"Enter number\n";` is being executed.

What would be the reason behind it and what is the possible solution.

Note: Without the `cin.ignore()` the program enters into an infinite loop

Comment: You are a little too generous with your sprinkling of `cin.ignore();`.

Answer (score 0):

Edited following comments:

`cin.ignore()` is expecting some input and simply ignores it. You should move this line in the `if` statement after `cout << "invalid input \n";`.

Comment: Because you call cin.fail() twice! In the else statement, you should add a 'break' to exit the loop instead.

Comment: @BenoitThiery That's incorrect.  You can call `cin.fail()` as often as you like (and if there's no intervening input, you're guaranteed to get the same value).  That's the one thing he got right.

Comment: Right, sorry for the confusion. You should do the cin.ignore() only if you receive bad input, so in the if statement after the cout and not at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: even if the `cin.ignore` is made the last line of the loop, the loops enters an infinite loop.

Comment: @debal Can you show the new source code and the input provided? Also, it should not be the last line of the loop, but just after cout << "invalid input \n";

Comment: @BenoitThiery If there's invalid input, you want to ignore _all_ of it, not just one character.  And of course, you have to reset the error state for the ignore to work.  I'd write the code differently, but if he wants to keep the present structure, he needs to 1) only do the ignore if the stream has failed, and 2) clear the error status _before_ doing the ignore.  Or clear the error.

Comment: @BenoitThiery If he clears the error status at the end of the loop (in the `if`), then he will never loop.  If he adopts this policy, he'll need an additional flag (probably the best solution without creating a separate function---but IMHO, the separate function is better).

Answer (score 0):

```
   cin.ignore();
   cin.clear();
   /* Input the number from the user*/
   cout << "Enter number\n";
   cin >> a;
```

to

```
   /* Input the number from the user*/
   cout << "Enter number\n";

   cin.clear();
   cin.ignore();
   cin >> a;
```

Comment: Which will still ignore at least one character, so if the user enters `"42"`, it will display `"2"`.  (And if the user enters `"abc"`, it will loop four times before accepting input.)

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with what you are doing.  The first
is as Benoit said: you are calling `cin.ignore()` too early,
before you output the prompt.  `cin.ignore()` will extract
exactly one character from the input stream (unless the input
stream has failed, or it encounters end of file).

The second is that when you loop (say because the user has
entered `"abc"`), you call `cin.ignore()` *before* resetting the
error, so it is a no-op.  If the user enters anything but
a number, you will loop forever, because you will be stuck on
the bad input.  You should probably put the `cin.clear()` in the
branch of the `if` which handles the error.  (Of course, this
means that you'll need some sort of flag to test in the
`do...while`, since the error will have been cleared by the time
you get there.  Alternatively, you *can* put the `clear` and the
`ignore` at the top of the loop, but in an `if`, so you only do
them if `cin.fail()`.)

The third is that you ignore exactly one character.  If the user
inputs `"abc"`, this will loop four times (`"abc"` plus the new
line) before waiting for his input.  The usual solution is to
ignore up through the next newline:

```
cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

This should be done *after* you input the `int` (probably
whether you fail or not, but since you're exiting if you don't
fail, it doesn't really matter if you don't do it then).

Finally, two points on style: the ubiquitous way of interogating
whether input has succeeded or not is to treat the stream as
a boolean:

```
if ( !cin ) {
    //  error...
} else {
    //  OK...
}

//  ...
} while ( !cin );
```

I'm not saying that it's good practice (in many ways, I prefer
your style), but it is so ubiquitous that anything else causes
the reader of your code to start, and to ask why you did
something different.

And I'd separate the input with prompt into a separate function,
and write something like:

```
template <typename T>
std::istream&
inputWithPrompt( std::istream& source, std::string const& prompt, T& dest )
{
    std::cout << prompt;
    source >> dest;
    return source;
}

int
main()
{
    int a;
    while ( !inputWithPrompt( std::cin, "Enter a number:", a ) ) {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max, '\n' );
        std::cout << "Invalid input" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Number entered is: " << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This seems a lot cleaner to me: loop until you succeed, then do
the successful output after you leave the loop.  (It might be
worth putting the clean-up code, the `clear` and the `ignore` in
a separate function as well.  If you're inputting using `>>`,
you'll need it often enough.)